# Back referencing object with mapstruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, builder, mapstruct

I have these entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@SuppressWarnings("java:S2160") // "Subclasses that add fields should override equals" - we only compare on id here.
public class AutorEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "game")
    private List<BookEntity> books = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class BookEntity extends BookBaseEntity {

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "author_id",
                nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private AuthorEntity autor;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pages")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class PagesEntity extends PagesBaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "book_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "page_id", referencedColumnName = "page_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private BookEntity book;

}
```

Similarly my domain objects:

```
@Builder
public record Author(List<Book> books) implements BaseAuthor {}
```

```
@Builder
public record Book(List<Page> pages, Author author) implements BaseBook {}
```

```
@Builder
public record Page(Book book) implements BasePage {}
```

and my mapstruct mappers:

```
@Mapper(uses = {
        BookEntityMapper.class
})
public interface AuthorEntityMapper {

    AuthorEntity toEntity(Author author);

    Author toDomain(AuthorEntity authorEntity, @Context SomeContext ctx);
}
```

```
@Mapper(uses = {
        PageEntityMapper.class
})
public interface BookeEntityMapper{

    BookEntity toEntity(Book book);

    @Mapping(target = "author", ignore = true)
    Book toDomain(BookEntity bookEntity, @Context SomeContext ctx);
}
```

the `PageEntityMapper` looks similar.
If I leave it this way and build the project the generated `Impl` classes would now exclude the author back reference in the book. If I remove the `ignore = true` then I get an error:  `Unmapped target properties: "books". Mapping from property "AuthorEntity author" to "Author author".`. How can I solve this within my mappers. I tried doing @AfterMapping but I can't inject the Author bean inside the Book. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance